# replacing A/C condenser – without having to drain R134a refrigerant?

Tags: ac, radiator, cobalt, condenser

The vehicle (Chevy Cobalt 2009) ran over a deer and bent inward the radiator and A/C condenser.  I'm going to replace both, however I'm wondering if it's possible to replace the condenser without having a lot of refrigerant leaking out.

I could take it to a shop and have them drain the all the refrigerant, but the car overheats quickly so I cannot drive it far.

I have a vacuum pump and manifold gauges,  but I don't have a recovery tank.  Is it possible to pressurize the system in a way that I can replace the condenser without leaking out refrigerant?

Comment: Have it towed, or fit a temporary shorter belt avoiding the a/c compressor, Howie's answer is good.

Comment: BTW - Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

No.  There would need to be valves either side of the condenser to limit gas loss, but even then you would still lose a condenser full of gas.  You would then have the problem that you have a new condenser full of air that would be released into the system.

The A/C needs emptying, repairing, vacuuming then refilling.

Comment: Thanks.  I will see if I can get an HVAC guy to come by and drain it to a recovery tank